# Python list implementation and pympler measurement

Tags: python, list, memory, size

I need to parse file (~500 Mb) and partially load it to `list`, I don't need the entire file.

I had a feeling that python allocate much more memory for the `list` that the size of the data it contains.

I tried to use `asizeof` of `pympler` in order to estimate the overkill however it fails with `MemoryError` which is strange for me, I thought if I have a `list` in the memory  `asizeof` should just run over it sum the sizes of all entities and that it.

Then I took the chunk of the initial file, and I was shocked by the size of the list `asizeof` showed me. The list size was three times bigger that the file size.

The question is if the size given by `asizeof` is correct, what the more efficient way to use list in python. How to check the size of the bigger list when `asizeof` fails with memoryerror.

Comment: List of what?  If it's line-based, just iterate the open file object rather than loading all lines ...

Comment: What do you actually need to do with the file? If you only need one line at a time, iterate over the file. There's overhead that will make a list of the file's lines significantly bigger than the file itself if the lines are short, but that should be addressed by not loading much of the file at once.

Comment: @wim, I wish I could iterate, I need the data from file in memory and I think ~500Mb it is not extremely huge file

Comment: "I need the data from file in memory" - yes, but what do you need to *do* with it?

Comment: @user2357112, count occurrences and cooccurences, based on counting do more stuff with the data

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to see the code you use for reading/parsing the file and also how you invoke `pympler.asizeof`.

`asizeof` and all other facilities in Pympler work inside the profiled process (using Python's introspection facilities to navigate reference graphs). That means that the profiling overhead might become a problem when sizing reference graphs with large number of nodes (objects) - especially if you are already tight on memory before you start profiling. Be sure to set `all=False` and `code=False` when calling [`asizeof`](http://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/library/asizeof.html#pympler.asizeof.asizeof). In any case, please [file a bug on GitHub](https://github.com/pympler/pympler/issues?state=open). Maybe one can avoid running out of memory in this scenario.

To the best of my knowledge, the sizes reported by `asizeof` are accurate as long as `sys.getsizeof` returns the correct size for the individual objects (assuming Python >= 2.6). You could set `align=1` when calling asizeof and see if the numbers are more in line with what you expect.

You could also check the virtual size of your process via your platform's tools or [`pympler.process`](http://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/library/process.html):

```
from pympler.process import ProcessMemoryInfo
pmi = ProcessMemoryInfo()
print ("Process virtual size [Byte]: " + str(pmi.vsz))
```

This metric should always be higher than what `asizeof` reports when sizing objects.